# How do I add an accordian to a card in React Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, react-bootstrap, card

I have a card and I want the text to be collapse-able.  I know accordions can do that.  For some reason it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why.  Is this possible and if not is there a solution.

```
 import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion'

      return (
      <Card className="cardClass">
        <Card.Img  className="card-image" variant="top" src={movie.ImagePath} />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{movie.Title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{movie.Genre.Name}</Card.Text>
          <Card.Text>
          <Accordion>
  <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
    <Accordion.Header>Summary</Accordion.Header>
    <Accordion.Body>
      {movie.Description}
    </Accordion.Body>
  </Accordion.Item>
  </Accordion>
          </Card.Text>
          <div className="card-btns">
            <Link to={`/movies/${movie._id}`}>
              <Button className="movieCard-btn" variant="primary">View Movie</Button>
            </Link>
          <Button className="movieCard-btn" variant="primary" value={movie._id} onClick={(e) => this.addFavoriteMovie(movie)}>Add Favorite</Button>
          </div>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to download the latest version of React Bootstrap